# Python Assignment Operator Precedence - (a, b) = a[b] = {}, 5

Tags: python, variable-assignment

I saw this Python snippet on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/fijall/status/634260102795685890) and was quite confused by the output:

```
>>> a, b = a[b] = {}, 5
>>> a
{5: ({...}, 5)}
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From the [*Assignment statements* documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements):

> An assignment statement evaluates the expression list (remember that this can be a single expression or a comma-separated list, the latter yielding a tuple) and assigns the single resulting object to each of the target lists, from left to right.

You have two assignment target lists; `a, b`, and `a[b]`, the value `{}, 5` is assigned to those two targets from left to right.

First the `{}, 5` tuple is unpacked to `a, b`. You now have `a = {}` and `b = 5`. Note that `{}` is mutable.

Next you assign the same dictionary and integer to `a[b]`, where `a` evaluates to the dictionary, and `b` evaluates to `5`, so you are setting the key `5` in the dictionary to the tuple `({}, 5)` creating a circular reference. The `{...}` thus refers to the same object that `a` is already referencing.

Because assignment takes place from left to right, you can break this down to:

```
a, b = {}, 5
a[b] = a, b
```

so `a[b][0]` is the same object as `a`:

```
>>> a, b = {}, 5
>>> a[b] = a, b
>>> a
{5: ({...}, 5)}
>>> a[b][0] is a
True
```

Comment: Hmm that's surprisingly unintuitive for Python! I would expect it to cascade from right to left and thus throw a `NameError`, with `a[b] = a, b = {}, 5` working.

Comment: Excellent answer. I figured out what was going on before I posted and was planning on posting a response, but you answered it very well. Also, +1 for the `a[b][0] is a` line.

Comment: Nice answer! But the docs say _assigns the **single resulting object** to each of the target lists, from left to right_, so shouldn't it be equivalent to `a, b = {}, 5; a[b] = {}, 5`?

Comment: @Claudio: that order only applies in languages where assignment is an expression and thus have a result to return. That forces the right-to-left order. In Python assignment is a statement and follows the natural reading order instead.

Comment: @SunQingyao: did you expect `{}, 5` to be evaluated twice when assigning? Why should it be? `{}` is *still the same object*. It's the equivalent of `d = {}; a, b = d, 5; a[b] = d, 5`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think it should be something like `tmp0, tmp1 = {}, 5; a, b = tmp0, tmp1; a[b] = tmp0, tmp1`, so that there won't be a circular reference.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ahh I understand now! `a` is just a reference to `{}`, which is **mutable**! So even in `tmp0, tmp1 = {}, 5; a, b = tmp0, tmp1; a[b] = tmp0, tmp1`, the value (or "referenced object") of `a` is still `{5: ({...}, 5)}`

Comment: @SunQingyao: exactly. Assigning the tuple to a key in that dictionary you created a reference to itself.