# What does `{...}` mean in the print output of a python variable?

Tags: python, ellipsis

Someone posted [this interesting formulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127908/python-assignment-operator-precedence-a-b-ab-5), and I tried it out in a Python 3 console:

```
>>> (a, b) = a[b] = {}, 5
>>> a
{5: ({...}, 5)}
```

While there is a lot to unpack here, what I don't understand (and the semantics of interesting character formulations seems particularly hard to search for) is what the `{...}` means in this context? Changing the above a bit:

```
>>> (a, b) = a[b] = {'x':1}, 5
>>> a
{5: ({...}, 5), 'x': 1}
```

It is this second output that really baffles me: I would have expected the `{...}` to have been altered, but my nearest **guess** is that the `, 5` implies a tuple where the first element is somehow undefined? And that is what the `{...}` means? If so, this is a new category of type for me in Python, and I'd like to have a name for it so I can learn more.

Comment: It is called an "ellipsis", please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772124/what-does-the-python-ellipsis-object-do) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python/112316#112316)

Comment: this has nothing to do with python's ellipsis object

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's an indication that the dict recurses, i.e. contains itself.  A much simpler example:

```
>>> a = []
>>> a.append(a)
>>> a
[[...]]
```

This is a list whose only element is itself.  Obviously the repr can't be printed literally, or it would be infinitely long; instead, the builtin types notice when this has happened and use `...` to indicate self-containment.

So it's not a special type of value, just the normal English use of "..." to mean "something was omitted here", plus braces to indicate the omitted part is a dict.  You may also see it with brackets for a list, as shown above, or occasionally with parentheses for a tuple:

```
>>> b = [],
>>> b[0].append(b)
>>> b
([(...)],)
```

Python 3 provides some tools so you can do this with your own objects, in the form of [`reprlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/reprlib.html).