# How to understand this assignment statement in Python?

Tags: python

I tried in the snippet below:

```
a, b = a[b] = {}, 5
print('a={0},b={1}'.format(a,b))
```

The IDE spits out the follows:

```
a={5: ({...}, 5)},b=5
```

I have tried `S3DEV`'s advice and execute:

```
from dis import dis
dis('a, b = a[b] = {}, 5')
```

And it gives me the follows:

```
  1       0 BUILD_MAP                0
          2 LOAD_CONST               0 (5)
          4 BUILD_TUPLE              2
          6 DUP_TOP
          8 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
         10 STORE_NAME               0 (a)
         12 STORE_NAME               1 (b)
         14 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
         16 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
         18 STORE_SUBSCR
         20 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
         22 RETURN_VALUE
```

But I still cannot understand why `a[b] = a, 5` happened in the step `18 STORE_SUBSCR`. Any further explanation?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244277/discussion-on-question-by-jimmy-zhao-how-to-understand-a-b-ab-5-in-py).

Comment: If you'd like to see the bytecode leading to the assignment, you can use: `from dis import dis`, then `dis('a, b = a[b] = {}, 5')`. This will show the steps taken to parse and execute this statement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does \`{...}\` mean in the print output of a python variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32408387/what-does-mean-in-the-print-output-of-a-python-variable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an [assignment statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) with multiple [target_list:s](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-python-grammar-target_list), for which case the docs say that the statement "assigns the single resulting object to each of the target lists, from left to right." Within each target_list, assignments also proceed left to right.

Thus, the statement is equivalent to

```
a = {}
b = 5
a[b] = a, 5
```

The reason that the last assignment is `a[b]=a,5` and not `a,b={},5` is that the value (`{}, 5`) is only evaluated once, so it's the *same* dict that gets used throughout. First, `a` is set to refer to that dict, then the dict — through `a` — is modified to refer to itself.

EDIT: Perhaps it is clearer to say that the statement is equivalent to

```
temp1 = {}
temp2 = 5
a = temp1
b = temp2
a[b] = temp1, temp2
```

Right before the last step, `a` and `temp1` refer to the same object, which thus becomes self-referring after the last step.

This is not code I want to see in production. :)

Comment: Nice answer. Perhaps include the statement from the docs "Assignment is defined recursively ..." which is why the ellipsis is populated to the dict.