# Strange inline assignment

Tags: python, tuples, variable-assignment

I'm struggling with this strange behaviour in Python (2 and 3):

```
>>> a = [1, 2]
>>> a[a.index(1)], a[a.index(2)] = 2, 1
```

This results in:

```
>>> a
[1, 2]
```

But if you write

```
>>> a = [1, 2]
>>> a[a.index(1)], a[a.index(2)] = x, y
```

where `x, y != 2, 1` (can be `1, 1`, `2, 2` , `3, 5`, etc.), this results in:

```
>>> a == [x, y]
True
```

As one would expect. Why doesn't `a[a.index(1)], a[a.index(2)] = 2, 1` produce the result `a == [2, 1]`?

```
>>> a == [2, 1]
False
```

Comment: You asked a strange question. Why should `a[a.index(1)], a[a.index(2)] = 2, 1` print anything at all? :)

Comment: I mean when requesting the value of a. I'm abusing notation. XD

Comment: Related (and devious): http://stackoverflow.com/q/32127908/3001761

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because it actually gets interpreted like this:

```
>>> a = [1, 2]
>>> a
[1, 2]
>>> a[a.index(1)] = 2
>>> a
[2, 2]
>>> a[a.index(2)] = 1
>>> a
[1, 2]
```

To quote, per the [standard rules for assignment](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) (emphasis mine):

> - If the target list is a comma-separated list of targets: The object must be an iterable with the same number of items as there are targets
>     in the target list, and the items are assigned, **from left to right**, to
>     the corresponding targets.

The assignment to `a[a.index(1)]` (i.e. `a[0]`) happens *before* the second assignment asks for `a.index(2)`, by which time `a.index(2) == 0`.

You will see the same behaviour for any assignment:

```
foo = [a, b]
foo[foo.index(a)], foo[foo.index(b)] = x, y
```

where `x == b` (in this case, any assignment where the first value on the right-hand side is `2`).

Comment: Can you reference the assignment order in Python from the docs?

Comment: Upvoted and accepted. Thank you for your great work!

Comment: Why does ``a = 1; a, b = 2, a`` result in ``b == 1`` then? You might want to discuss the differences between mutable and immutable objects in your answer.

Comment: @pzp that's not mutable vs. immutable, that's because the right-hand side is fully evaluated before any of the assignments begin. The same thing would happen with a mutable `a`.