# Python Order Of Assignment

Tags: python

Python assignment order behaves differently than I expected. In javascript I could write this:

```
x = {};
a = x;

a = a['y'] = {};

console.log(a);
// {}

console.log(x)
// {'y':{}}
```

Because assignment happens right to left, in `a = a['y'] = {};`, `a['y']` gets assigned `{}`, then `a` gets assigned `a['y']`- which is `{}`;

However, in python this is not the case. The same setup:

```
x = {}
a = x

a = a["y"] = {}

print(a)
# {"y": {...}}

print(x)
# {}
```

In python, this makes `a` a self-referencing object, and doesn't set "y" on `x` at all. The assignment can't be left to right, because assigning `a = a["y"]` before "y" is set would throw an error. So what is python doing here and why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32127960/4256283

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python's assignment "operator" `=` is a dedicated statement, not an expression; your code is not a composition of two assignment expressions like it is in JavaScript, but one single statement that allows for the possibility of multiple targets. When used with multiple targets, Python:

1. Stores to targets from left to right
2. Duplicates the same reference to each target

So this means:

```
a = a["y"] = {}
```

is equivalent to:

```
__unnamed_tmp = {}
a = __unnamed_tmp
a["y"] = __unnamed_tmp
```

in that order, causing the behavior you observe.

Comment: Also see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements), which back this up and give the full, general semantics.